# Интегрирование методом средних прямоугольников и трапеций

Tags: c++

Мне необходимо написать функцию на С++, которая будет получать на вход адрес на функцию (одну из y=x, y=sin(22*x), y=x^4, y=arctan(x)), концы отрезка интегрирования (a ∊ [0,1], b ∊ [2,3]), дельту - разницу между двумя последовательными итерациями, а также n, которое, изменяясь, будет показывать количество столбцов разбиения. Суть метода мне ясна, функция работает для y=x, y=x^4, y=arctan(x), но в функции y=sin(22*x) начинаются проблемы при     |b-a|/2=1.

[image: Ответ верный при а=0, b=3]

[image: Ответ неверный при а=0, b=2]

Проблема состоит в том, что значения первых двух итераций при |b-a|/2=1 будут меньше, чем заданная дельта (т.е при eps=10e-6 функция работать будет).
Вопрос заключается в том, как избежать эту ситуацию в функции y=sin(22*x).

```
double IntRect(TPF f, double a, double b, double eps, int& n) {
    double dx = (b - a) / 2;
    double s1=5;
    double s2=0;
    s2 = f(a) * dx + f(a + dx) * dx;
    while (abs(s2-s1) > eps){
        s1 = s2;
        dx = dx/2;
        n = n*2;
        s2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            s2 = s2 + f(a + dx * i);
        }
        s2 *= dx;
    }
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: Либо, задавать минимальное число отрезков разбиения. Либо, проверять точность на текущем разбиении не только сравнением с предыдущем разбиением, но и сравнением с другим методом методом. Например, для метода отрезков, можно брать не правую точку отрезка, а случайную точку (этакий метод моте-карло).